# iOS version of my app not shown on fabric dashboard

Tags: ios, crashlytics, google-fabric

In my my fabric dashboard I am not been able to view my iOS app currently whereas I can see the Android app.I have updated my app to latest SDK(from 10.2 to 11.4) and I have been recently added to the team. It used to be there before.What can be the possible issue?As the fabric and crashlytics pods are there configured in my app.

Comment: do a force crash & it will appear in next 5 minutes.